# How to search in column A for specific data and return an answer in column B ("Yes" or "No")

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Using Excel for Mac 2008.
I'm looking for a formula that will do two things: search in Column A and provide a result from the search in Column B. Column A has a long list of comma-separated data in no good order. I want to find one specific set of words (set off by commas, such as "Level 2 Supporter") in each row. Then I want the formula to give me a result in Column B (True/False, Yes/No, etc.) I will sort by column B to get the final results I need. How might I do this?

Column A Example:
Row 1)Mag Temp- good,2014 YE Renewal Email,Members 11/5/13,Nsl - Temp,Level 2 Supporter
Row 2)Members 05/09/14,Nsl - Temp,Magney Mailing Temp,Members 11/5/13

Result in Column B:
Row 1) Yes
Row 2) No

Comment: I find this confusing.  Can you produce a short mock-up of what your existing data look like and what results you want to get?  (Do this by [editing](http://superuser.com/posts/907784/edit) the question, not in a comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the importance of the quotations is (unless you have lots of data in each cell and you are only after the data with quotations as your search criteria). Then you may need a vba function to split your data.

If column A is filled with your mixed data and column B is blank and you only want to check cells against their counterparts in column A. You could use a conditional statement with a search function:

=If(IsNumber(Search("Level 2 Supporter",A1)),"True","False")

The Search() formula will return an index number if Level 2 Supporter is found, if it isnt it will not return a number. When this is wrapped in an IsNumber() function, it will return true or false which is the criteria for your IF statement.

Which uses this form:
=IF(logic_test, value_if true, value_if_false)

This formula is dragged down in column B next to column A, if the cell next to it contains "Level 2 Supporter", True is displayed, if it doesn't you will get a False.

If you want to search the whole column and test whether your value exists in column A you will need a vlookup, if this is the case please let me know and I will elaborate.